# How to implement DAO in Scala?

Tags: scala, dao

I would like to implement DAO in Scala as follows:

```
trait DAO[PK,-T,-Q] {

   // T is a "value object", PK is a primary key, and Q is query parameters.

   def create(t:T):Unit
   def update(t:T):Unit
   def remove(pk:PK):Unit
   def find(query:Q):Seq[T]
}
```

Does it make sense ? Doesn't it look "too Java" ?
How would you design/implement DAO in Scala ?

Comment: It depends upon the "heart" of what a DAO should be -- which is a very subjective topic ;-)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Being ORM agnostic or implementing Active Record pattern? If you want to implement Active Record there are already ORMs that do so...

Comment: Depending on what you are looking to do Lift provides a ful featured ORM so you wont have to roll out your own

Answer (score 4):

I think Scala allows more direct and straightforward work with SQL databases than Java'ish DAO.

You may want to check out http://squeryl.org/ and other frameworks mentioned in this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362748/wanted-good-examples-of-scala-database-persistence/2318935#2318935

Comment: Really appreciate the link to that other answer.  Very helpful, thank you!

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this like me, the linked post can be found at the [internet archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20141006104858/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362748/looking-for-a-comparison-of-scala-persistence-frameworks/2318935).